# writing ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to know how I can write a Ruby regular expression that indicates it should start with alphanumeric characters followed by only alphanumeric and `-` (in any sequence) after that.

So to begin with alphanumeric I know it's:

```
/\A[A-Za-z0-9]/
```

How do I say I can only allow alphanumeric characters and `-` after this? I am new to Ruby and regular expressions. Any suggestions ?

Are there any links I can look into for learning about regular expressions and Ruby in much more depth? I found http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_regular_expressions.html to be useful.

Comment: http://rubular.com is great for testing...

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ is also a great one for real-time matching and flags. Recommended by many users of Rubular. If you want better answers however, please provide examples of the kind of data you want to match.

Answer (score 3):

You already have the initial alphanumeric character class `[A-Za-z0-9]`. For the next characters, you just want to add `-` to this: `[A-Za-z0-9-]`. Hence the final regex is:

```
[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*
```

Note that `X*` means *"`X` 0 or more times"*. If you want *"`X` 1 or more times"*, use `X+`.

Comment: Thank you for your response..however using [A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]+ doesn't seem to work on rubular.com  . I tried putting in your regex and it doesn match for single characters

Comment: @Bearish_Boring_dude What's your test string?

Comment: I may have not been clear with my question .. a Single alpha numeric character is also permissible

Answer (score 0):

```
r1 = /^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*$/ #=> /^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*$/
r2 = /^[A-Za-z0-9-]*$/            #=> /[A-Za-z0-9-]*$/

str = "3birdsweresittingonawire-nowtherearebuttwo"

str =~ r1 #=> 0 (truey)
```

or

```
(str =~ r2) and str[0] != '-' #=> true


str = " % 3birdsweresittingonawire-nowtherearebuttwo"

str =~ r1                     #=> nil
(str =~ r2) and str[0] != '-' #=> nil
```

The second example shows why you need the anchors `^` and `$`.